# defining methods within an interface

Tags: c#, interface, xna

first of all let me apologize for asking so many stupid questions. i am just starting at c# and trying to get my head around classes/interfaces and inheritance. in this example i have three classes that share an interface. like this;

```
public  class Platform : IGraphic
{
    public GraphicType Type;        
    public string Name;
    public Texture2D Icon;

    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public Texture2D GetIcon(GraphicType a_type)
    {
        if (a_type == Type || a_type == GraphicType.CHARACTERS)
            return Icon;
        else
            return null;
    }

}

public class Decal : IGraphic
{
    public GraphicType Type;        
    public string Name;
    public Texture2D Icon;

    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public Texture2D GetIcon(GraphicType a_type)
    {
        if (a_type == Type)
            return Icon;
        else
            return null;
    }

}

public  class Character : IGraphic
{
    public GraphicType Type;        
    public string Name;
    public Texture2D Icon;

    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public Texture2D GetIcon(GraphicType a_type)
    {
        if (a_type == Type || a_type == GraphicType.CHARACTERS)
            return Icon;
        else
            return null;
    }

}

public interface IGraphic
{
    string GetName();
    Texture2D GetIcon(GraphicType a_type);
}
```

when i call GetName() it works perfectly but when i try to call GetIcon() i get an error message;
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D'
what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show the call that gets the error.

Comment: have you tried stepping through it with the debugger to see exactly where the error occurs? Where is your code calling the GetIcon function?

Comment: my apologies. i had; if (icon = item.GetIcon(a_type) != null) and i should have had if ((icon = item.GetIcon(a_type)) != null)

Comment: thank you very much for your help. your questions made me revisit the code

Comment: did you find the wrong code?

Comment: as i mentioned above. i didn't have enough braces in my if statement